file_put_contents(/var/www/html/app/Policies/House/HousePolicy.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
./vendor/bin/sail artisan shield:install


                                                                        FOLLOWING OPERATIONS WILL BE PERFORMED:


   INFO  - Publishes core package config.

   INFO  - Publishes core package migration.

   WARN  - On fresh applications database will be migrated.

   WARN  - You can also force this behavior by supplying the --fresh option.

 ┌ Do you wish to continue? ────────────────────────────────────┐
 │ Yes                                                          │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

   INFO  Seems you have already installed the Core package(`spatie/laravel-permission`)!

   INFO  You should run `shield:install --fresh` instead to refresh the Core package tables and setup shield.

 ┌ Run `shield:install --fresh` instead? ───────────────────────┐
 │ Yes                                                          │
 └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

   INFO  Publishing assets.

  File [config/permission.php] already exists .............................................................................................. SKIPPED
  File [database/migrations/2024_06_24_091940_create_permission_tables.php] already exists ................................................. SKIPPED

   INFO  Core Package config published.

   INFO  Publishing [filament-shield-config] assets.

  File [config/filament-shield.php] already exists ......................................................................................... SKIPPED

   INFO  Freshening up shield migrations.

   INFO  Running migrations.

  2024_06_24_091940_create_permission_tables .......................................................................................... 1 ثانیه DONE


   INFO  Generating permissions ...


   ErrorException

  file_put_contents(/var/www/html/app/Policies/House/HousePolicy.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:204
    200▕      * @return int|bool
    201▕      */
    202▕     public function put($path, $contents, $lock = false)
    203▕     {
  ➜ 204▕         return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);
    205▕     }
    206▕
    207▕     /**
    208▕      * Write the contents of a file, replacing it atomically if it already exists.

      +32 vendor frames

  33  artisan:13
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::handleCommand()


can any one help me ?
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
and
find /var/www -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # folder
find /var/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644 # files
and this
php artisan cache:clear
chmod -R 777 storage/
composer dump-autoload
but still i have problem

I'm guessing you're not running the command as www-data. I've found the easiest way is to add your user to the www-data group, and make the full project directory group-writable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel has some good information on it
